# How to create a controller for an SQL View for app that uses Code First?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-mobile-services

I created an SQL view for use in my app's mobile backend. Probably because of the term "View" and "MVC", i'm having a difficult time looking for possible solutions cos i keep getting links to View of MVC rather than SQL View.

Anyone know how to create a controller that references an SQL View?

Comment: what do you mean saying controller?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a controller that handle this for you but I can provide an example to let you understand what mean create an MVC view and retrieve related data.

Suppose you have your SQL Server View like in this example:

```
CREATE VIEW StackUserScores AS 
  SELECT u.Username, s.Score
  FROM Users u INNER JOIN UserScores s ON s.UserId = u.Id
```

After you can create an object view that can display all your data:

```
public class StackUserScores {
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create, in your asp.net MVC project, a new controller called `UsersController`. This controll will contain all `actions` related to the users:

```
public class UsersController : Controller {
  public ActionResult Scores() {
    var connectionString = "your db connection";
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StackUserScores";
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    var scores = new List<StackUserScores>();
    while( reader.Read()) {
      scores.Add(new StackUserScore {
        Username = reader.GetString(0),
        Password = reader.GetInt(1)
      });
    }
    return View(scores);
  }
}
```

You view (that will be places in ~/Views/Users/Scores.cshtml) will be like this:

```
@model List<StackUserScore>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Username</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach(var userScore in Model) {
    <tr><td>@userScore.Username</td>
        <td>@userScore.Score</td>
    </tr>
  }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please remember that: this is one of infinite list of approach to this problem. You can use Entity Framework or something else,  in this example I provide you a demo using a custom class (StackUserScore) and custom data retrieve (using SqlCommand).

I Hope this can help you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

@Roberto described how to create the SQL View:

```
CREATE VIEW StackUserScores AS 
  SELECT u.Username, s.Score
  FROM Users u INNER JOIN UserScores s ON s.UserId = u.Id
```

Once you have the SQL View, you can create a TableController within an ASP.NET application using the Azure Mobile Apps SDK:

```
public class TodoItemController : TableController<StackUSerScores>
{
    //...
}
```

The StackUserScores must be a DTO - an entity class that inherits from `EntityData`.  In addition, the view must support the relatively simple fields required for Azure Mobile Apps.  These include:

- [string] id
- [DateTimeOffset] createdAt
- [DateTimeOffset] updatedAt
- [string] version
- [boolean] deleted

These are added to your DTO by inheriting from EntityData but you need to account for them in your SQL View since the SDK won't be able to add them for you.  The biggest downfall people run into is the id, which needs to be a string, not an integer.

Obviously, being a View, your view will be read-only.

Comment: FYI, the view can be updatable if it has entities from only one table. You can even make an updatable view with multiple tables if you add an update trigger.